# how to add an alphabet with condition value more than one in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to add alphabet at the end of no_surat but with the condition, it has more than 1 same value in the account field, if account only has 1 value it will not add an alphabet

I already try this query but it also added an alphabet to account that has only 1 value like in account no 335, an account that has only 1 value like 355, should have no added alphabet account 335 should have no_suratABC No.SKF.161

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, NO_SURAT, no_suratABC 
 FROM 
 (SELECT *, concat((NO_SURAT) , CHR(64 + CAST ( row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER   order by ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS integer ))) AS No_suratABC 
FROM 
 (SELECT DISTINCT ON (ADDRESS) * FROM account_information) a) b;
```

I have this data record

```
|account   |    no_surat  | no_suratABC|
|-----     |    ------    |      ----- |
|337       |    No.SKF.6  | No.SKF.6A  |
|337       |    No.SKF.5  | No.SKF.5B  |
|337       |    No.SKF.4  | No.SKF.4C  |
|335       |    No.SKF.161| No.SKF.161A|
|184       |    No.SKF.105| No.SKF.105A|
|184       |    No.SKF.71 | No.SKF.71B |
```

any suggestion on how I should add in my query?

Comment: Which letter(s) should appear in the sequence after `Z` ?

Comment: we don't have account more than z

Comment: Keep in mind the difference between "don't" and "can't" Also that as a designer/developer part of your job is the systematic control of of things that cannot happen - cause they can, they do and they will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` here to choose which letter appears:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (ADDRESS) *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT ORDER BY NO_SURAT DESC) rn,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT) cnt
    FROM account_information
)

SELECT ACCOUNT, NO_SURAT,
       CASE WHEN cnt > 1
            THEN CONCAT(NO_SURAT, SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' FROM rn::int FOR 1))
            ELSE NO_SURAT END AS No_suratABC
FROM cte;
```

The trick used above is to take a 1-length substring of the alphabet string `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, using the row number to decide which letter to choose.  Note that I assume here that you would never require a letter label beyond `Z`, which assumes that each account would never have more than 26 records associate with it.

Comment: i got error > ERROR:  function pg_catalog.substring(unknown, bigint, integer) does not exist

Comment: @omik Try casting the row number to integer, i.e. use `FROM rn::int FOR 1`, q.v. the updated answer above.

Comment: it's still adding alphabet to an account that has only 1 value

Comment: I added a fix for that, though you never mentioned this requirement in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic approach is fine.  Just fix the syntax and put in the logic to do what you want.  What you describe is:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, NO_SURAT,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT) > 1
             THEN NO_SURAT || (CHR(64 + CAST (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT ORDER BY ACCOUNT)::int)
             ELSE NO_SURAT
        END) as No_suratABC
FROM account_information;
```

However, your sample data suggests that you want:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, NO_SURAT,
       (NO_SURAT || CHR(64 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT ORDER BY ACCOUNT)::int)) as No_suratABC
FROM account_information;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=20eebdb7b2bb99b2a1514a17d33bf94e) is a db<>fiddle.